# Java cloning with static variable

Tags: java

How do I write the cloning function for a class with static variables?

```
class Vehicle implements Cloneable {
    private double degree;
    private double speed;
    private String owner;
    private long ID;

    static private long nextID;
    Vehicle(){
        this.ID = Vehicle.nextID++;
    }

    Vehicle(String name) {
        this();
        owner = name;
    }

    public Vehicle clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        try {
            Vehicle v = (Vehicle)super.clone();
            v.ID = Vehicle.nextID++;
            return v;
        } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e){
            throw new InternalError(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the correct implementation?

Comment: Well it's not thread-safe, to start with... but then it wasn't even before you introduced the `clone()` method. Ultimately it depends on what you *want* this to mean... I'd expect a `clone()` to preserve the existing ID, but maybe you have different requirements.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on thread-safe? ID is the unique key, so it should be new for the cloned objects.

Comment: Well, mutating a static variable without any locking like this simply isn't thread-safe. Two calls from different threads could end up using the same IDs, or various other issues. You should be using `AtomicLong`. But fundamentally, if the clone doesn't have the same data as the old object, I wouldn't call it `clone()`.